# Help with an SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables.  Let's call them  a, b, and a_to_b.  a_to_b contains (among other things) the unique ids from both a and b to provide linkage between a and b (obviously). a looks something like this:

```
a_id, max_b, ...
```

a_to_b looks something like:

```
a_id, b_id, ...
```

I would like to create a query that is something like:

```
select a.a_name, a.max_b, a_to_b.(number of times a_id appears in a_to_b) for a, a_to_b where ...
```

only I don't know the right questions to ask google to find out how to do it.

To summarize, I don't care about the the individual occurrences of b_id in a_to_b, just how many times a_id appears in that table.

I hope that made enough sense to be able to see what I'm trying to accomplish.  Thanks for the help.

*EDIT*

Now that I run it I realize that I am missing part of the query.

This is the full story.  Sorry for the previous misdirection.

table A:

```
group_id
other_stuff
```

table B:

```
user_id
other_stuff
```

table A_to_B:

```
group_id
user_id
m_type (int used to determine user's role in the group)
```

Desired output:

```
a.group_id, a_to_b.count(of group_id where m_type=4), b.user_id (user_id from a_to_b from the group_id that was grouped where m_type=2)
```

Again, I apologize for the repost.  I should have been more careful when asking the first time.  I wish I were familiar enough with this stuff to be able to translate what Rasika gave but I tried a bunch of stuff and mysql just keeps yelling at me.

*MORE EDIT*

I did some more experimenting on what Rasika wrote and came up with this mess:

```
select classes.class_id, classes.spaces - ifnull(dUtC.students,0) as openings, classes.semester_id, dUtC.teacher, users.fname, users.lname from (select teachUtC.class_id as class_id, numUtC.students as students, teachUtC.user_id as teacher from (select class_id, count(*) as students from users_to_classes where participation_level=4 group by class_id) as numUtC right join (select class_id, user_id from users_to_classes where participation_level=2) as teachUtC on teachUtC.class_id=numUtC.class_id) as dUtC, classes, users where users.user_id=dUtC.teacher and dUtC.class_id=classes.class_id
```

It works but I can't help but think that I am doing it wrong...  I'd like to know if there is a cleaner way to write that.

Thanks

Comment: Can you try to distill the question to a more simple statement. First, what should the output table look like? What is the simplest schema that you can represent your problem in. If you are going to remove students, etc. then do so fully.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to suggest.  I thought that I had laid it out as simply as possible, but like I said, i don't know the right words to describe the situation in text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [group by](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) with a count to generate this.

```
select a.a_name, a.max_b, count(*) as num_a_id from a join a_to_b on a.a_id=a_to_b.a_id group by a_id
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was trying to do.  I love how fast everyone here is.  Thanks a ton.